# Comparing the first principal component with an observed variable (mean)?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, mean, factor-analysis

I want to see how using the mean of my variables instead of the first principal component helps represent (the first dimension) of my data. The idea is that if those are similar enough, I might as well use the mean, which is much easier to explain. In mathematical term, I want to compare basically $X v$ ($v$ first eigenvector of $\Sigma$) to $X \tilde{1}$ ($\tilde{1}$ is vector of (1,1, ..., 1)/p, $p$ is number of variables)

Is there a literature dealing with similar concerns? Which methods would be suggested? I can think of three metrics:

1. Compute the first PCA, and the mean. Measure their correlation.
2. Compute the variance from first PCA, and variance from mean. See how much is lost by using mean instead of PCA.
3. Compare the first eigenvector, to the mean weight vector (1,1, ..., 1)/p, take some measure of distance between those two.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an instance of the problem factor analysis is trying to address: make slight (linear) modifications of the principal components ("rotate" them) to create interpretable factors.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has often been discussed; one keyword is comparision of "centroid-rotation" vs. "pc-rotation", another one is "parcels" vs. "item-factor-analysis" (or so, I may not be up-to-date).
The computation of the items-mean is here in principle equivalent with determining the "centroid", and if multiple means are taken from multiple subsets of items, then this is in principle "parceling".

When items are strongly anticorrelated, then the centroid (=mean) item the positive- and negative values in the data extinguish each other and the data of the centroid have small variance and are thus not well configured to determine the "main-direction" of the factor. Opposite to this, PCA handles anticorrelated data in the same way as correlated data, and in such cases should be the better option.

Here is a small protocol with random data based on 4 items, 2 relevant factors and 4 itemspecific errors. All items load strongly on the first factor, but the second pair with negative loading. This should spoil the "mean"/"centroid"-solution

```
construction table "ULAD" for 4 items from 2 "relevant" factors 
                                       and 4 "itemspecific" factors
The factor-loadings are unstandardized, so the variance in the items is <>1
See the anti-correlated loadings on the first random factor "f 1" between pairs 
    of items: 

ULAD |     f 1 |     f 2 |  err 1 |  err 2 |  err 3 |  err 4
 ------------------------------------------------------------
it 1 |  1.0000 |  0.1000 | 0.3000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000
it 2 |  1.0000 |  0.3000 | 0.0000 | 0.4000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000
it 3 | -1.0000 |  0.2000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.1000 | 0.0000
it 4 | -1.0000 | -0.2000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.4000

[22] data = ulad*ufac   // generate "empirical" data from random vectors("ufac")
                        // We have n=1000 cases from random-generator with
                        // normal distribution in datamatrix "UFAC"
```

The data-items get their mean-vector appended as 5'th data-vector:

```
[23] data = {data,meansp(data)}  // append to data-matrix the columnwise means
                                 // as new data-vector
```

Show covariances:

```
[24]   cov=data   *' /n     // operator *' makes dotproduct with transpose.

 COV |    it 1 |    it 2 |    it 3 |    it 4 |   mean
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 |  1.1341 |  1.0229 | -1.0097 | -1.0299 | 0.0293
it 2 |  1.0229 |  1.2059 | -0.9346 | -1.0391 | 0.0638
it 3 | -1.0097 | -0.9346 |  1.0742 |  0.9615 | 0.0228
it 4 | -1.0299 | -1.0391 |  0.9615 |  1.1754 | 0.0170
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean |  0.0293 |  0.0638 |  0.0228 |  0.0170 | 0.0332
```

Note the small variance in the "means"-vector!
Show correlations:

```
[30]   R=covtocorr(cov)

 R   |    it 1 |    it 2 |    it 3 |    it 4 |   mean
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 |  1.0000 |  0.8747 | -0.9148 | -0.8920 | 0.1511
it 2 |  0.8747 |  1.0000 | -0.8211 | -0.8728 | 0.3187
it 3 | -0.9148 | -0.8211 |  1.0000 |  0.8556 | 0.1209
it 4 | -0.8920 | -0.8728 |  0.8556 |  1.0000 | 0.0858
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean |  0.1511 |  0.3187 |  0.1209 |  0.0858 | 1.0000
```

We do solution for principal components. The program allows, to do the rotation taking respect ***only for selected subsets of items***

```
[35]   lad=cholesky(R)
[36]   pc=rot(lad,"pca",1..4)   // rotate to pc only using items 1..4 for criterion

  PC |     pc1 |     pc2 |     pc3 |     pc4 |    pc5
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 |  0.9685 | -0.1018 | -0.0434 |  0.2231 | 0.0000
it 2 |  0.9379 |  0.2918 | -0.1801 | -0.0528 | 0.0000
it 3 | -0.9445 |  0.2881 |  0.0656 |  0.1437 | 0.0000
it 4 | -0.9521 | -0.1019 | -0.2866 |  0.0323 | 0.0000
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean |  0.0689 |  0.5488 | -0.6674 |  0.4986 | 0.0000
```

We see, that the mean-vector is completely uncorrelated to the first principal component of the first four items. This is, because their main loadings neutralize for the centroid.

Let's look at it from the view, whether the "means"-vector capture the principal component, when taken as leading item:

```
[149]   pca=rot(lad,"pca",5)         // use "means"-vector alone for first pc
[150]   pca=rot(pca,"pca",1..4,2..5) // use it1-it4 for 2'nd,3'rd,4'th,5'th pc

  PC |    pc1 |     pc2 |    pc3 |     pc4 |    pc5
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 | 0.1511 | -0.9606 |  0.1497 | -0.1791 | 0.0000
it 2 | 0.3187 | -0.9179 | -0.1555 |  0.1781 | 0.0000
it 3 | 0.1209 |  0.9552 | -0.2437 | -0.1167 | 0.0000
it 4 | 0.0858 |  0.9601 |  0.2435 |  0.1071 | 0.0000
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean | 1.0000 |  0.0000 |  0.0000 |  0.0000 | 0.0000
```

The centroid, which we find indicated by "mean", does in no way collect the main direction or the main variance in the model. The with the mean uncorrelated second pc (first pc of the remaining variance of the items 1-4) has much more weight and represents the factor loadings much more reliable, with which the model was created.

---

Now we do the same analysis, but we create the four items as parallel (and positively) correlated to the first random factor:

```
ULAD |    f 1 |     f 2 |  err 1 |  err 2 |  err 3 |  err 4
 ------------------------------------------------------------
it 1 | 1.0000 |  0.1000 | 0.3000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000
it 2 | 1.0000 |  0.3000 | 0.0000 | 0.4000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000
it 3 | 0.6000 |  0.6000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.1000 | 0.0000
it 4 | 0.5000 | -0.8000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.4000
```

Generate data with the same random-vectors as before. Append "means"-vector as before. Show covariances:

```
[80]   cov=data *' /n

 COV |   it 1 |   it 2 |    it 3 |    it 4 |   mean
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 | 1.1341 | 1.0229 |  0.6504 |  0.4800 | 0.8218
it 2 | 1.0229 | 1.2059 |  0.7447 |  0.2962 | 0.8174
it 3 | 0.6504 | 0.7447 |  0.6977 | -0.1504 | 0.4856
it 4 | 0.4800 | 0.2962 | -0.1504 |  1.0837 | 0.4274
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean | 0.8218 | 0.8174 |  0.4856 |  0.4274 | 0.6380
```

See the better variance in "means"-vector!
Show correlations:

```
[85]   R=covtocorr(cov)

 R   |   it 1 |   it 2 |    it 3 |    it 4 |   mean
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 | 1.0000 | 0.8747 |  0.7312 |  0.4330 | 0.9661
it 2 | 0.8747 | 1.0000 |  0.8119 |  0.2591 | 0.9319
it 3 | 0.7312 | 0.8119 |  1.0000 | -0.1730 | 0.7278
it 4 | 0.4330 | 0.2591 | -0.1730 |  1.0000 | 0.5139
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean | 0.9661 | 0.9319 |  0.7278 |  0.5139 | 1.0000
```

Show PC-solution:

```
[90]   lad=cholesky(cor)
[91]   pc=rot(lad,"pca",1..4)

  PC |   pc 1 |    pc 2 |    pc 3 |    pc 4 |   pc 5
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 | 0.9578 | -0.1621 |  0.1929 | -0.1383 | 0.0000
it 2 | 0.9638 |  0.0357 | -0.2590 | -0.0526 | 0.0000
it 3 | 0.8547 |  0.4828 |  0.0771 |  0.1743 | 0.0000
it 4 | 0.3089 | -0.9446 | -0.0035 |  0.1108 | 0.0000
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean | 0.9746 | -0.2233 | -0.0057 |  0.0175 | 0.0000
```

Here we see, that - as hoped - the "means"-vector indeed roughly captures the "PC-1" factor, meaning the first principal component.

Again we change perspective:

```
[178]   pca=rot(lad,"pca",5)         \\ first pc from "means"-vector only
[179]   pca=rot(pca,"pca",1..4,2..5) \\ remaining pc's from "items"-residuals
                                     \\ only

  PC |    pc1 |     pc2 |     pc3 |     pc4 |    pc5
------------------------------------------------------ 
it 1 | 0.9661 |  0.0570 |  0.1991 | -0.1539 | 0.0000
it 2 | 0.9319 |  0.2500 | -0.2537 | -0.0690 | 0.0000
it 3 | 0.7278 |  0.6608 |  0.0792 |  0.1653 | 0.0000
it 4 | 0.5139 | -0.8523 |  0.0004 |  0.0976 | 0.0000
------------------------------------------------------ 
mean | 1.0000 |  0.0000 |  0.0000 |  0.0000 | 0.0000
```

We see, that the factor which is detected by the "mean"-vector, captures well the first pc of the "item"s.

---

Things are a bit more complicated when more items and more relevant principal components (or factors, in case one does a factor-analysis and not simply PCA) are in the game and subsets of items get "parceled" and are replaced by their respective "means"-vector.

About the details with the problems of the "parceling" you must read elsewhere, I think there's a lot of discussion and study online around.